# Error after installing the WordPress plugin updates

Tags: plugins, errors, updates

I have trouble after update WordPress plugin.

**"Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. check back in a minute."
and then
"This page isn’t working ptmitajayamandiri.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"**

I deleted the .maintenance file in Cpanel but it still hasn't been resolved.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the error log file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest  way to disable a plugin when there is no access to admin, is renaming of plugin folder.

Connect via ftp by Filezilla or use cpanel.

Comment: Just rename plugin that you have updated. Wordpress will ignore this plugin. Then you can try lower versions of. Plugin.